# How to Understand Flink Window Semantics?

Tags: apache-flink

Could anyone help me answer the question that if there is a 5s time window executing aggregation operations every 2s. The first 2s handle data in window between n and n+5 while the second 2s handle data in window between n+2 and n+7. It seems that the Flink do duplicate work in time of n+2 to n+5. is it that? Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If you apply a function, that could potentially reuse the result of the first window to compute the second window, currently Flink does not exploit this. Each window in computed from scratch. (However, this optimization in on the development agenda already and will be supported in future releases.)

Answer (score 3):

the windows that Flink processes should be (n, n+2), (n, n+4), (n+1, n+6), (n+3, n+8). So in the beginning the windows are not 5 seconds wide. It has to "catch up" because there is not enough time-data available yet. The window is processed every two seconds and it looks at the last 5 seconds from that point.

In general it is easier to think about windows if the slide size and window size have a greatest common divisor (GCD). Also, windows can then potentially be evaluated faster, using a pane-based approach.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should say the nth 2s handle data in window between m and m+5 while the (n+1)th 2s handle data in window between m+2 and m+7...